why doesn't npm install work properly in NestJS/ubuntu
I was working on a NestJS project, I recently moved from windows to Ubuntu and once I cloned the project from github on my linux, the npm install command doesn't work with the following error:
Precision-5530:~/projects/warehousing$ npm install
npm warn deprecated inflight@1.0.6: This module is not supported, and leaks memory. Do not use it. Check out lru-cache if you want a good and tested way to coalesce async requests by a key value, which is much more comprehensive and powerful.
npm warn deprecated rimraf@3.0.2: Rimraf versions prior to v4 are no longer supported
npm warn deprecated glob@7.2.3: Glob versions prior to v9 are no longer supported
npm warn deprecated glob@7.2.3: Glob versions prior to v9 are no longer supported
npm warn deprecated glob@7.2.3: Glob versions prior to v9 are no longer supported
npm warn deprecated glob@7.2.3: Glob versions prior to v9 are no longer supported
npm warn deprecated glob@7.2.3: Glob versions prior to v9 are no longer supported
npm warn deprecated glob@7.2.3: Glob versions prior to v9 are no longer supported
npm warn deprecated superagent@8.1.2: Please upgrade to v9.0.0+ as we have fixed a public vulnerability with formidable dependency. Note that v9.0.0+ requires Node.js v14.18.0+. See https://github.com/ladjs/superagent/pull/1800 for insight. This project is supported and maintained by the team at Forward Email @ https://forwardemail.net

> warehousing@0.0.1 postinstall
> patch-package

sh: 1: patch-package: not found
npm error code 127
npm error path /home/ikianm/projects/warehousing
npm error command failed
npm error command sh -c patch-package

npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: /home/ikianm/.npm/_logs/2024-07-16T17_49_41_064Z-debug-0.log

Everything was working fine on my windows and now this doesn't work.
I have NodeJS version 20.15.1 and npm version 10.7.0 installed.
here's the content of package.json just in case:
{
  "name": "warehousing",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "author": "",
  "private": true,
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "patch-package",
    "build": "nest build",
    "format": "prettier --write \"src//*.ts\" \"test//*.ts\"",
    "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development nest start",
    "start:dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development nest start --watch",
    "start:debug": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development nest start --debug --watch",
    "start:prod": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node dist/main",
    "lint": "eslint \"{src,apps,libs,test}/**/*.ts\" --fix",
    "test": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test jest",
    "test:watch": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test jest --watch",
    "test:cov": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test jest --coverage",
    "test:debug": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test node --inspect-brk -r tsconfig-paths/register -r ts-node/register node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand",
    "test:e2e": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test jest --config ./test/jest-e2e.json --logHeapUsage --runInBand --detectOpenHandles  --verbose --watchAll"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nestjs/common": "^10.0.0",
    "@nestjs/config": "^3.2.2",
    "@nestjs/core": "^10.0.0",
    "@nestjs/mapped-types": "^2.0.5",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^10.0.0",
    "@nestjs/typeorm": "^10.0.2",
    "axios": "^1.7.2",
    "class-transformer": "^0.5.1",
    "class-validator": "^0.14.1",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.2",
    "mysql2": "^3.10.0",
    "nestjs-request-context": "^3.0.0",
    "qs": "^6.12.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.2.0",
    "rxjs": "^7.8.1",
    "typeorm": "^0.3.20"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@commitlint/cli": "^19.3.0",
    "@commitlint/config-conventional": "^19.2.2",
    "@nestjs/cli": "^10.0.0",
    "@nestjs/schematics": "^10.0.0",
    "@nestjs/swagger": "^7.3.1",
    "@nestjs/testing": "^10.0.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.17",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.2",
    "@types/node": "^20.3.1",
    "@types/supertest": "^6.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.0.0",
    "eslint": "^8.42.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^5.0.0",
    "husky": "^9.0.11",
    "jest": "^29.5.0",
    "prettier": "^3.0.0",
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.21",
    "supertest": "^6.3.3",
    "ts-jest": "^29.1.0",
    "ts-loader": "^9.4.3",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^4.2.0",
    "typescript": "^5.1.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "ts"
    ],
    "rootDir": "src",
    "testRegex": ".*\\.spec\\.ts$",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "**/*.(t|j)s"
    ],
    "coverageDirectory": "../coverage",
    "testEnvironment": "node"
  }
}


Try installing patch-package as dev dependency using npm install patch-package --save-dev command and then rerun npm install

My apologies, Prior answer was not for this purpose.

I don't recall adding this "postinstall": "patch-package" to my package.json's scripts, is there a chance that this got added automatically by NestCLI?

It gets there only if one adds it explicitly.

no, I'm the only one working on this project and I've never done that, anyways, thanks for your response.

You can always remove it
